# How to write a JavaScript template class?

Tags: javascript, class, templates

I'm just a newer to JavaScript. I want to write a JS template class like C++. for example:

```
template <typename T>
class A
{
public:
    A(T x)
    {
        this.a=x;
    }
    ~A()
    {

    }
    void print()
    {
        std::cout<<a<<std::endl;
    }
private:
    T a;
};
```

We can use this class like this:

```
A<int> test(2);
test.print();
```

For C++, it's simple. But in JS, how it can be explained?  Thanks very much.

Comment: Why do you want a template class in a dynamically typed language?

Comment: I'm just translating C++ code to JS code, then come to this problem. Is there some way for this translation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do this:

```
var A = function ( x ) {
    var a = x;
    this.print = function () {
        console.log(a);
    };
};

var test = new A(2);
test.print(); // -> 2
```

In this case, the variable `a` is private, the function `print` is public (as is any other property of `this`), and `A` is the constructor function for the template (prototype object).

Comment: Maybe it works, but using this method can't reflect the 'template'. Without other method, maybe it's a good method. Thanks..

Answer (score 6):

Javascript does not need templates to handle generic types because Javascript is a [dynamically typed language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_system#Dynamic_typing). This means that in Javascript, functions can accept arguments of any type.

To achieve the same functionality as the example template in your question, you may use this (much shorter) Javascript code using object literals:

```
var A = {
  print: function(value) {
    document.write(value);
  }
}
```

This can be used like so:

```
A.print(2);
```

You can see this code sampe in action on [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yW96D/).

If you want the code to correspond more closely to the C++, you can use this approach using a function instead:

```
var A = function(value) {
  return {
    print: function() {
      document.write(value);
    }
  }
}
```

Which can be used like this:

```
var test = A(2);
test.print();
```

You can see this in action on [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jHCDr/).

Comment: I got it. Thank you and mVChr   :)

Answer (score 1):

Well in your case, since the template parameter is a type, you don't need to reflect it in Javascript.

But if you had something like a function pointer

```
typedef bool (*C) (const int&, const int&);

template<C c>
class my_class{

public:
    void my_method(){
        // use c 
        // ...
    }

};
```

You could translate it to

```
var my_class_t = function(c){

    var my_class = function(){
    };

    my_class.prototype.my_method = function(){
        // use c 
        // ...
    };

    return my_class;
};
```

And use it as follows

```
var my_class = my_class_t(function(a, b){return a < b;});
var my_instance = new my_class();
my_instance.my_method();
```